# Extra include files for hooks

Tags: hooks

I'd like to organize a .module file better by putting related hooks in other .inc files.  So for example, I'd like to take a bunch of imagecache preset definitions (via `hook_imagecache_default_presets`) out of custom.module and put them in custom.imagecache.inc.

Where in custom.module should I include custom.imagecache.inc?  I assume I'll be using `module_load_include()`?

If I put it in a `hook_init` wouldn't that include these hook definitions on every page request?

Comment: I would use hook_module_implements_alter(). But some people say this is a bad idea.. http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/108884/hook-module-implements-alter-to-put-hook-implementations-into-separate-files

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you have to put the hooks in the .module file. But what you can then do is call `module_load_include()` from within the hook function, and use the hook function itself as a wrapper.

So:

```
mymodule_hookfunction($arg) {
  module_load_include('inc', 'mymodule', 'includefile');
  return mymodule_function_that_is_in_the_include_file($arg);
}
```

This has the benefit of only loading the include file if the hook gets called.

NOTE: The answer really is `hook_hook_info()`, not this one.

Comment: Seems clean enough, I can relate to this solution.

Answer (score 8):

Current answer is not 100% correct for Drupal 7. In Drupal 7 there is a hook called [hook_hook_info](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_hook_info/7). In core this is implemented with the token module via [system_hook_info](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.module/function/system_hook_info/7). That means that for tokens the hook can be located inside of module_name.tokens.inc. So yes you can put hooks in related files by groups. Just remember that hook_hook_info must be inside of your .module file.

An example using [blocks](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!block!block.api.php/7)

```
<?php
/**
 * Implements hook_hook_info().
 */
function mymodule_hook_info() {
  $hooks['block_configure'] = array(
    'group' => 'blocks',
  );
  $hooks['block_info'] = array(
    'group' => 'blocks',
  );
  $hooks['block_info_alter'] = array(
    'group' => 'blocks',
  );
  $hooks['block_list_alter'] = array(
    'group' => 'blocks',
  );
  $hooks['block_save'] = array(
    'group' => 'blocks',
  );
  $hooks['block_view'] = array(
    'group' => 'blocks',
  );
  $hooks['block_view_alter'] = array(
    'group' => 'blocks',
  );

  return $hooks;
}
?>
```

You should be able to then use a mymodule.blocks.inc file to hold all your blocks information as long at the above code/hook is inside of your .module file.

Answer (score 3):

I would just take the simplier approach and add something like:

```
include_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/custom.imagecache.inc';
```

at the beginning of my custom.module file.